# Retrofit 2.7.2 GSON error when using a retrofit call, the error is "Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class ". Could not find a solution

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I am using android studio and kotlin attempting to make an API call using retrofit with gson library. I used the JSON to kotlin data class plugin to make my data classes. I have looked for solutions and havent been able to find anything that exactly matches my issue here. I looked up how to add a no args constructor in kotlin but that involves setting all the fields to default values which is not what I want. I wondered if somehow it was calling the API but not receiving anything in the conversion rates but I wasn't exactly sure how to check since I instantly get thrown the error when calling the API.

The exact error I am receiving is:

"Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.schrader.currency_take_two.data.models.ConversionRates. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem."

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.schrader.currency_take_two"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // dagger-hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.41'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.41'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'

    // coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'

    // ViewModel
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"

    //fragment KTX library
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"

    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"




    // Room DB
    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"


}
```

Here are the data classes one is shortened here because it is very long:

```
package com.schrader.currency_take_two.data.models


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class CurrencyResponse(
    @SerializedName("base_code")
    val baseCode: String,
    @SerializedName("conversion_rates")
    val conversionRates: ConversionRates,
    @SerializedName("documentation")
    val documentation: String,
    @SerializedName("result")
    val result: String,
    @SerializedName("terms_of_use")
    val termsOfUse: String,
    @SerializedName("time_last_update_unix")
    val timeLastUpdateUnix: Int,
    @SerializedName("time_last_update_utc")
    val timeLastUpdateUtc: String,
    @SerializedName("time_next_update_unix")
    val timeNextUpdateUnix: Int,
    @SerializedName("time_next_update_utc")
    val timeNextUpdateUtc: String
)

package com.schrader.currency_take_two.data.models

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ConversionRates(
    @SerializedName("AED")
    val aED: Double,
    @SerializedName("AFN")
    val aFN: Double,
    @SerializedName("ALL")
    val aLL: Double,
    @SerializedName("AMD")
    val aMD: Double,
    @SerializedName("ANG")
    val aNG: Double,
    @SerializedName("AOA")
    val aOA: Double,
    @SerializedName("ARS")
    val aRS: Double
)
```

Here is the retrofit call and my retrofit instance:

```
interface CurrencyApi {

    @GET("/v6/API_KEY/latest/{Currency}")
    suspend fun getRates(
        @Path("Currency") currency: String //This adds onto the API URL in the {} in the GET, @Query adds a query to the URL 'Query={Query}'
    ): Response<CurrencyResponse>
}
```

The API call doesnt make it to the first Log call and instantly errors out to the catch block.

```
class Default_API_Repository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: CurrencyApi
) : API_Repository {

    override suspend fun getRates(currency: String): Resource<CurrencyResponse> {
        return try{
            val response = api.getRates(currency)
            Log.d("API", "${response.toString()}")
                val result = response.body()
                if(response.isSuccessful && response != null ){
                    Resource.Success(result)
                }else{
                    Log.d("API", "${response.message()}")
                    Resource.Error(response.message())
                }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("API", "${e.message}")
            Resource.Error(e.message ?: "An error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com"


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCurrencyApi(): CurrencyApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CurrencyApi::class.java)
```

This is how I call the API in the main activity:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
               var response = apiRepo.getRates("USD")
               if(response.data == null){
                   Log.d("MAIN", "${response.message}")
               }
               Log.d("MAIN", "${response.toString()}")
            }
```

Here is the exact JSON from the API:

```
{
 "result":"success",
 "documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
 "terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
 "time_last_update_unix":1649203202,
 "time_last_update_utc":"Wed, 06 Apr 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "time_next_update_unix":1649289602,
 "time_next_update_utc":"Thu, 07 Apr 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "base_code":"USD",
 "conversion_rates":{
  "USD":1,
  "AED":3.6725,
  "AFN":88.6534,
  "ALL":110.0838,
  "AMD":480.1007,
  "ANG":1.7900,
  "AOA":445.0124,
  "ARS":111.4453,
  "AUD":1.3155,
  "AWG":1.7900,
  "AZN":1.6961,
  "BAM":1.7892,
  "BBD":2.0000,
  "BDT":85.2904,
  "BGN":1.7884,
  "BHD":0.3760,
  "BIF":2005.2598,
  "BMD":1.0000,
  "BND":1.3581,
  "BOB":6.8635,
  "BRL":4.6151,
  "BSD":1.0000,
  "BTN":75.3175,
  "BWP":11.5278,
  "BYN":2.8692,
  "BZD":2.0000,
  "CAD":1.2468,
  "CDF":1995.8399,
  "CHF":0.9283,
  "CLP":779.3730,
  "CNY":6.3692,
  "COP":3716.7222,
  "CRC":660.0122,
  "CUP":24.0000,
  "CVE":100.8701,
  "CZK":22.2978,
  "DJF":177.7210,
  "DKK":6.8247,
  "DOP":54.9168,
  "DZD":143.1850,
  "EGP":18.2463,
  "ERN":15.0000,
  "ETB":51.2293,
  "EUR":0.9148,
  "FJD":2.0753,
  "FKP":0.7634,
  "FOK":6.8247,
  "GBP":0.7634,
  "GEL":3.0853,
  "GGP":0.7634,
  "GHS":7.7634,
  "GIP":0.7634,
  "GMD":54.8016,
  "GNF":8946.2447,
  "GTQ":7.6691,
  "GYD":209.6041,
  "HKD":7.8373,
  "HNL":24.5487,
  "HRK":6.8925,
  "HTG":107.4322,
  "HUF":341.7488,
  "IDR":14374.8444,
  "ILS":3.2117,
  "IMP":0.7634,
  "INR":75.3200,
  "IQD":1462.3970,
  "IRR":41938.4058,
  "ISK":129.1085,
  "JEP":0.7634,
  "JMD":153.5796,
  "JOD":0.7090,
  "JPY":123.3508,
  "KES":115.6196,
  "KGS":85.8864,
  "KHR":4057.0179,
  "KID":1.3156,
  "KMF":450.0508,
  "KRW":1215.3051,
  "KWD":0.2996,
  "KYD":0.8333,
  "KZT":466.7579,
  "LAK":13220.0876,
  "LBP":1507.5000,
  "LKR":295.1163,
  "LRD":152.7083,
  "LSL":14.6202,
  "LYD":4.6812,
  "MAD":9.4783,
  "MDL":18.3389,
  "MGA":3035.6361,
  "MKD":56.0557,
  "MMK":1825.6103,
  "MNT":2954.7230,
  "MOP":8.0723,
  "MRU":36.4708,
  "MUR":44.3148,
  "MVR":15.4209,
  "MWK":820.4555,
  "MXN":19.9358,
  "MYR":4.2051,
  "MZN":64.2611,
  "NAD":14.6202,
  "NGN":415.4445,
  "NIO":35.8669,
  "NOK":8.7398,
  "NPR":120.5080,
  "NZD":1.4357,
  "OMR":0.3845,
  "PAB":1.0000,
  "PEN":3.6681,
  "PGK":3.5228,
  "PHP":51.2574,
  "PKR":183.8781,
  "PLN":4.2286,
  "PYG":7064.7743,
  "QAR":3.6400,
  "RON":4.5173,
  "RSD":107.6495,
  "RUB":83.3695,
  "RWF":1058.3464,
  "SAR":3.7500,
  "SBD":7.8290,
  "SCR":14.3972,
  "SDG":445.3390,
  "SEK":9.4126,
  "SGD":1.3582,
  "SHP":0.7634,
  "SLL":11827.2387,
  "SOS":579.5740,
  "SRD":20.7475,
  "SSP":425.3169,
  "STN":22.4125,
  "SYP":2511.1358,
  "SZL":14.6202,
  "THB":33.5163,
  "TJS":12.5014,
  "TMT":3.5000,
  "TND":2.7588,
  "TOP":2.2203,
  "TRY":14.7205,
  "TTD":6.7529,
  "TVD":1.3156,
  "TWD":28.6146,
  "TZS":2322.3918,
  "UAH":29.1999,
  "UGX":3547.1133,
  "UYU":41.2934,
  "UZS":11432.7976,
  "VES":4.4095,
  "VND":22865.8925,
  "VUV":110.6141,
  "WST":2.5488,
  "XAF":600.0677,
  "XCD":2.7000,
  "XDR":0.7277,
  "XOF":600.0677,
  "XPF":109.1646,
  "YER":250.3338,
  "ZAR":14.6364,
  "ZMW":17.6268,
  "ZWL":142.3748
 }
}
```

Comment: Try to initialize them. I mean your data class.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Initialize them in general? Or do you mean during the API call? The reason I ask is because if I understand correctly Gson will take the response and convert it to the given data class. I initialized the data class in main activity to see if that works and it does, I edited the longer class for convenience but the principal should hold. Here is the original tutorial I was following, and editing a bit to practice different things: [https://github.com/philipplackner/CurrencyConverter](https://github.com/philipplackner/CurrencyConverter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize them. One of the reason maybe the value is `null`.

```
data class CurrencyResponse(
    @SerializedName("base_code")
    val baseCode: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("conversion_rates")
    val conversionRates: ConversionRates? = null,
    @SerializedName("documentation")
    val documentation: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("result")
    val result: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("terms_of_use")
    val termsOfUse: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("time_last_update_unix")
    val timeLastUpdateUnix: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("time_last_update_utc")
    val timeLastUpdateUtc: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("time_next_update_unix")
    val timeNextUpdateUnix: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("time_next_update_utc")
    val timeNextUpdateUtc: String? = null
)
```

Comment: I see, thank you for helping, it was really this simple. I'm still a bit confused though because in the tutorial his classes were the same format as mine with no initialization to null. Is this the rule of thumb to always initialize the data class values to null when using them for API calls?

Comment: @Caffeine_Relapser AFAIC, you need to initialize variables to invoke as constructor class. If this answer helps you, you can tick '✓' button as the correct answer.